# ASP.NET Global/Static storage?

Tags: asp.net, static, request, appdomain

I have a thread-safe object which is part of an API previously used in windows service/client scenarios. This thread-safe object is essentially a singleton and stored in a static variable so that all callers can access the same state.

This API has recently started being used in an ASP.NET application, and I suspect that some funky behavior we're seeing may be due to unexpected AppDomain/lifecycle behavior. So I was wondering if I could get some verification:

Is a static variable reliably available for *all requests*, or does ASP.NET do any trickery with having multiple AppDomains for multiple requests?

*I understand this would be the case for a web garden ... but our IIS is configured to use only 1 process, and is configured to only recycle once a day*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variable should be the same for all requests in 1 worker process. I would suggest you to add logs to your asp.net application, especially in application_start/stop and in static constructor of a singleton to see what's happening.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought but wanted to double verify my assumption. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. In .NET the scope of a static variable is the AppDomain, not the process. An ASP.NET worker process can host more than one AppDomain.

Comment: @richb, is there a reason why would you do this in real ASP.NET app?

Comment: Kirill if you have multiple applications defined on IIS using the same worker process, each will have its own AppDomain. You could assign each application to a different worker process, but its perfectly valid not to do that.